# Method 'loadFactoriesFrom' is deprecated

Tags: php, laravel

In have recently upgraded to Laravel 8 but now I am receiving a warning

> Method 'loadFactoriesFrom' is deprecated

My file structure is like below

```
myapp/
├── packages/
│   ├── package-1/
|   |   |── src/
|   |   |   |── databases/
|   |   |   |   |── factories
|   |   |   |   |   |── PackageModel11
|   |   |   |   |   |── PackageModel12
|   |   |   |   |── Package1ServiceProvider
|   |   |   |   └── migrations
|   |   |   |── models/
|   |   |   |── controllers/
|   |   |   |── migrations/
|   |   |   └── /
|   |   |── tests/
|   |   |── composer.json/
│   ├── app
│   ├── database/
│   ├── resources/
│   └── public/
```

To Load my custom package I use various functions

```php
<?php

namespace MyName\Package1;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class Package1ServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadFactoriesFrom(['database/factories']);
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes.php');
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/migrations');
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/views', '');
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/views' => base_path('resources/views'),
        ]);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        // Register controllers Here 
    }
}
```

How do I load these factories now that `loadFactoriesFrom` is deprecated?

### Update

I found here how I can [connect models and Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#connecting-factories-and-models) and they document to override the `newFactory()` function.

So I have below in my Test

```php
  public function testWithPermissionUserCanSaveNewOnlineAssessment()
  {
    $topic = ELearningTopic::factory()->create();
    $this->actingAs($this->user, 'api')
      ->post('api/e-learning/course-content/topics/.' . $topic->id . './online-assessments', [])
      ->assertStatus(401);
  }
```

My Factory

```php
class ELearningTopicFactory extends Factory
{
  public function definition()
  {
     return [
       'name' => 'Some name'
     ];
  }
}
```

And my Model

```php
  use HasFactory;
  protected static function newFactory()
  {
    return ELearningTopicFactory::new();
  }
```

Now I am getting Error Below

> Class 'App\ELearningTopic' not found

What could I be missing? why isnt the model class overridden

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 8 changed the way factories work.

anyway, if you want to use old factory style in laravel 8, just install laravel
[legacy-factories](https://github.com/laravel/legacy-factories)

This package provides support for the previous generation of Laravel factories (<= 7.x) for Laravel 8.x+.

for more detail about this issue, see this [github link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/34190).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I found a better solution here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#connecting-factories-and-models.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked

You can add the following code inside the ServiceProvider in the register:

```
namespace JobMetric\Setting;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

public function register(): void
{
    ...

    Factory::guessFactoryNamesUsing(function (string $modelName) {
        return "\\JobMetric\\Setting\\Factories\\" . class_basename($modelName) . 'Factory';
    });
}
```

I put this code in the jobmetric/laravel-setting package